# 2D Array Length

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to create a 2D array but get the row and column value from an integer, example;

```
    Integer Col = 8;
    Integer Row = 200;

    String[][] list;

    list = new String [Row][Col];
```

Of course, this is not compling. Im getting a Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String error but I am not trying to convert an int to a String, I just want the Integer value to set the array length.

Comment: This part works fine for me ! Share the whole code

Comment: public class Beta1 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  Integer Col = 8;
  Integer Row = 200;
  int i = 0;
  
  String[][] list;
  
  list = new String [Row][Col];
    
  list[5][100] = 27;
  
  System.out.println(list[5][100]);
  
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your environment setup is correct?
Because your code looks good, [see here](http://ideone.com/7JVhRy) .

```
public class Main {

    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        Integer Col = 8;
        Integer Row = 200;

        String[][] list;

        list = new String[Row][Col];
        System.out.println( list.length );

    }
}
```

I just renamed the class and added a print statement to show something useful, nothing more :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting the "cannot convert from int to String error" is because you are storing an 27(integer) to list(which is a string datatype). `list[5][100] = 27`. For storing an integer into a string datatype, you have to explicitly convert the integer to string using `String.valueOf()` or `Integer.toString` --

```
public class Beta1 { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Integer Col = 200; 
    Integer Row = 8; 
    int i = 0; 
    String[][] list; 
    list = new String [Row][Col]; 
    list[5][100] = String.valueOf(27); 
    System.out.println(list[5][100]); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: This is giving me; Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
 at Beta1.main(Beta1.java:16)

Comment: Ahh. this was because the number of columns was 8 and you are accessing the 100 position. Change the row and column values, I have edited the code.